# Button onclick having problems redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems redirecting users to another page using a button

(assume hostname is `localhost:8000`)

```js
$('#getFruit').attr('onclick', window.location.host + '/getFruit/banana')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="getFruit">Get Fruit</button>
```

This should redirect me to `localhost:8000/getFruit/banana`. However, i got this error in the console

`Uncaught ReferenceError: banana is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

It seems that the browser thinks that banana is a variable.

Any fixes for this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? you are just setting the attribute `onclick` to some value. Try this way if you are looking to redirect. `$('#getFruit').click(function(){ window.open( window.location.host + '/getFruit/banana', '_blank'); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A URL is not a valid value for the `onclick` attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick) Your current code is actually trying to run the URL as Javascript when a user clicks the button, which won't work.

You should try redirecting the user using Javascript:

```js
$('#getFruit').click(function() {
  window.location = '/getFruit/banana';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="getFruit">Get Fruit</button>
```

Comment: I see, got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to onclick, e.g.

```js
$('#getFruit').on('click', function() { window.location = '/getFruit/banana'; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="getFruit">Fruit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
$('#getFruit').click(function() { location.href = location.host + '/getFruit/banana'})
```